# JQuery show divs and form elements based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have minimal JQuery experience. Simple things like show/hide divs, etc. What I am trying to accomplish is to show/create new form elements based on a drop down value and assign id values.

So if I select option 5 for example from a drop down, it should display or write the #group div 5 times and assign a value to. The following example would be if I selected option 5 how I am trying to get it to come out. If I did 10 or 20, it would display 10 times, or if I did 2, it would display 2 times. I can accomplish this with document.write outside of jquery, but it seems like there would be a easier way...

```
<select name="amount" id="amount" title="amount">
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <option value="04">04</option>
  <option value="05" selected="selected">05</option>
  <option value="06">06</option>
  <option value="07">07</option>
  <option value="08">08</option>
  <option value="09">09</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div id="group">
<input name="group[1][]" type="checkbox" id="group[1][]" title="group[1][]" value="1">
<input name="group[1][]" type="checkbox" id="group[1][]" title="group[1][]" value="2">
<input name="group[1][]" type="checkbox" id="group[1][]" title="group[1][]" value="3">
<input name="group[1][]" type="checkbox" id="group[1][]" title="group[1][]" value="4">
</div>

<div id="group">
<input name="group[2][]" type="checkbox" id="group[2][]" title="group[2][]" value="1">
<input name="group[2][]" type="checkbox" id="group[2][]" title="group[2][]" value="2">
<input name="group[2][]" type="checkbox" id="group[2][]" title="group[2][]" value="3">
<input name="group[2][]" type="checkbox" id="group[2][]" title="group[2][]" value="4">
</div>

<div id="group">
<input name="group[3][]" type="checkbox" id="group[3][]" title="group[3][]" value="1">
<input name="group[3][]" type="checkbox" id="group[3][]" title="group[3][]" value="2">
<input name="group[3][]" type="checkbox" id="group[3][]" title="group[3][]" value="3">
<input name="group[3][]" type="checkbox" id="group[3][]" title="group[3][]" value="4">
</div>

<div id="group">
<input name="group[4][]" type="checkbox" id="group[4][]" title="group[4][]" value="1">
<input name="group[4][]" type="checkbox" id="group[4][]" title="group[4][]" value="2">
<input name="group[4][]" type="checkbox" id="group[4][]" title="group[4][]" value="3">
<input name="group[4][]" type="checkbox" id="group[4][]" title="group[4][]" value="4">
</div>

<div id="group">
<input name="group[5][]" type="checkbox" id="group[5][]" title="group[5][]" value="1">
<input name="group[5][]" type="checkbox" id="group[5][]" title="group[5][]" value="2">
<input name="group[5][]" type="checkbox" id="group[5][]" title="group[5][]" value="3">
<input name="group[5][]" type="checkbox" id="group[5][]" title="group[5][]" value="4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a `#groups` div that I could append the rows to and also clear each time a new number was selected from the drop down.  I also added a zero default value to start from.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#amount').change(function(){
   $('#groups').empty();
   var group = '';
   var number = parseInt($(this).val());
   for(var i=1;i<=number;i++){
     group += '<div id="group">' +
     '<input name="group['+i+'][]" type="checkbox" id="group['+i+'][]" title="group['+i+'][]" value="1">' +
     '<input name="group['+i+'][]" type="checkbox" id="group['+i+'][]" title="group['+i+'][]" value="2">' +
     '<input name="group['+i+'][]" type="checkbox" id="group['+i+'][]" title="group['+i+'][]" value="3">' +
     '<input name="group['+i+'][]" type="checkbox" id="group['+i+'][]" title="group['+i+'][]" value="4">' +
     '</div>';
    }
    $('#groups').append(group);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L73cd/1/

Comment: I really appreciate your help! This idea saved me a ton of time.